# How do I use the channel defaults when uploading a video using the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

We upload videos to channels using the YouTube API v2. I had figured that if I didn't specify the [accessControl](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Setting_Access_Controls) node in the xml that it would use the channel default, but it seems to use the YouTube default instead (they are marked with asterisks on the page).

How do I get my uploaded videos to use the channel defaults?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and we are hoping to have it fixed soon. There is an internal report but feel free to file a public one to be notified when it's fixed.
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)